# Angular Material 2 - Responsive Toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

Using Angular 4 I am trying to have a toolbar on the top of the page that has the following behaviour:

### Big Screens

Show the "Main"-Logo/Link on the left, the other top-nav links
on the right.

### Small screens

Show the "Main"-Logo Link centered and a menu button on the left for showing the sidenav (containing the links that were visible on the right if the screen is big).

#### Note:

The sidenav should not go over the toolbar if visible.

#### Note 2:

The centering of the "Main"-Logo/Link should be centered regarding the overall screen width. It should not be pushed to the right by the menu button.

### What I have

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button md-button routerLink="/">
      <md-icon>code</md-icon>
      <span>{{title}}</span>
    </button>
    <div fxFlex fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm></div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
      <button md-button routerLink="/about">About</button>
      <button md-button routerLink="/legal">Legal Notice</button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-sidenav-container fxFlex>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
      <md-nav-list>
        <a md-list-item href="">Main</a>
        <a md-list-item href="/about">About</a>
        <a md-list-item href="/legal">Legal Notice</a>
      </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>
  </md-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

### Where I struggle

- I do not know how to center the "Main"-Logo/Link correctly
- If I show the menu in a small screen and switch back the layout to a bigger screen, the menu does not hide

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated, so thank you already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Answer to your **First** Question:

Create a css class say `fill-space` and use that to center the logo:

```
.fill-space {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

... and in your template:

```
<span fxFlex fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm class="fill-space"></span>
<button md-button routerLink="/">
  <md-icon>code</md-icon>
  <span>{{title}}</span>
</button>
<span class="fill-space"></span>
```

> Answer to your **Second** Question:

You will have to `close()` the sidenav manually on screen resize. You can detect that using `@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])`:

In your typescript, do the following changes:

```
// Import the following in your ts file
import { ViewChild, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material';

// Add the following in your component class to get sidenav
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MdSidenav;

// Add the method to detect screen-resize
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    if(this.sidenav !== undefined){
        this.sidenav.close();
    } 
}
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iuaahz?file=app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Why can't you just use `fxFlex` instead of using the CSS `flex`?

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can also see in the sample, the "code" element has a small offset to the right that corresponds to the width of the menu button.

Comment: you can fix the margin using `style="margin-left: -24px"`, I have updated the demo. Please upvote and accept when you are satisfied with the answer :)

Comment: I had to change it to `40px` but other than that it worked. Thank you!